# Alert to detect when pods are in the Pending state for more than 15 minutes

Tags: kubernetes-pod, datadog

I want to detect when Kubernetes pods are in a pending state for more than 15 minutes. I have tried to use the query below in Datadog to achieve this, using the kube state metrics core integration for metric collection:

```
max(last_15m):exclude_null(max:kubernetes_state.pod.age{pod_phase:pending} by {kubernetescluster,kube_namespace,pod_name}) / 60 >= 15
```

The query checks in theory checks the age of the pod, and if more than 15 minutes old and the pod hasn't gone into a running state, it should alert. The results have been quite inconsistent. The query seems to be trigger when pods no longer exists, i.e they have been killed and removed from the cluster. Can someone help me understand the best way to construct the correct query?